Why int **m its not equal to int m[][]?
I'd like to clarify a concept that I haven't been able to fully understand.
Why in C is the type int **m compatible with int *m[N], but not with int m[N][N]? An 2D-array can be seen as a pointer to an array of integers, so int (*m)[N]. However, it could also be seen as an array of pointers to integers, so int *m[N]. What I don't understand is why int **m cannot be seen as int m[][] but as int *M[], while int m[][] can be seen as int (*m)[] but not as int **m.
I apologize if this explanation seems a bit confusing.

Read this: Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays.  TLDR:  pointers are variables that contain an address that may or may not be valid.  Arrays are regions of memory that have an address.  Those are not the same thing.

An array can be seen as a pointer to an array of integers. wrong

This question is similar to: What is array-to-pointer conversion aka. decay?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Tip: int m[n][n] is a contiguous block of integers that has one address. int *m[n] is a contiguous block of pointers. Each element of that array points to an integer. The location(s) of those integers could be scattered anywhere in memory. Draw and label pictures full of boxes and arrows and you'll begin to understand more...

@Chris The question is entirely clear and certainly does not need debugging details. It is also not exactly the question linked in your comment: Sure, the issue underlying the confusion is array "decay", but here the question is specifically about 2-D arrays. Also, the linked question is about C++ and the accepted answer consequently talks also about references; the computational correctness crowd here always insists that the two languages are very different and should not be confused, cross-tagged, mentioned in the same sentence or even thought about together, so no: Voted to repoen.

int m[X][Y] couldn't possibly decay into an int ** since m contains no pointers to which the int ** could point.
Array T m[X] decays into a pointer to its first element (&m[0]) when used as a pointer. Since the element has type T, this pointer will obviously have the type T *.



Example m
T, the type of m[0]
T *, the type of &m[0]




int m[X]
int
int *


int m[X][Y]
int[Y]
int (*)[Y]



Here's how you could pass a 2d array (so to speak) to a function:
void f( size_t x, size_t y, int (*m)[y] ) {
   // ...
}

int m[X][Y];
f( X, Y, m );


It is probably confusing to the OP because it is the exception to the C rule that declaration mimics usage, caused by the (repeated!) type conversion from array to pointer.

There may be such an exception in there, @Peter-ReinstateMonica, but I'm uncertain what, exactly, you mean by that.

The confusion is normal (common even) since pointers and arrays are highly interchangeable (though obviously not entirely so). It wouldn't be surprising if int m[X][Y] were to decay into int **. In my opinion, the only thing that's holding that back is the need to allocate Y pointers. (This has two problems: 1. Not every system has dynamic memory allocations, and 2. They couldn't be freed once allocated.)

int = 0, *pi = &i, **ppi = &pi, ai2d[1][1]; usage of pi and ppi reflects their declaration: *pi = 0; **ppi = 0;. This is a universal feature of C declarations, helpful to parse function pointer types etc. Usually, usage of ai2d does, too: ai2d[0][0] = 0; But is is also possible to (correctly) write **ai2d = 0; because of array decay. Of course, this is already true for 1D-arrays: after int ai[1]; both the regular ai[0]=0 and the "irregular" *ai = 0; are possible. The double decay in the 2D case is just more confusing, perhaps also because of confusing arrays of pointers etc.
